# As a Brit, how do I invest in US ETFs

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, etf, international, vanguard

Specifically, I'm interested in the [Vanguard High Dividend Yield ETF](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=0923&FundIntExt=INT). I actually live in China and don't plan on returning to the UK for the foreseeable future. Although I have some UK investments, I'd like to spread my risk out a bit more globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanguard has [just recently started listing its funds in London](https://www.vanguard.co.uk/uk/mvc/investments/etf) but it doesn't look like the High Dividend Yield ETF is available yet.

You'll need to either get a broker who can trade on the U.S. markets (there might be tax and exchange rate complications), or wait until Vanguard lists this stock on the London exchange.

Comment: Aren't there brokerage companies based in the U.K. that can trade on U.S. stock markets on behalf of their U.K.-based clients?  As a Canadian, I can buy U.S.-listed stocks through my Canadian broker.  The only complication there is in my purchasing U.S.-listed securities is the exchange rate (which my broker takes care of, for a fee) and U.S. withholding taxes on dividends.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea: You may be right. I've updated the answer to reflect this.